# Validate mobile number in magento 2

Tags: magento2, form-validation

Hi i want to validate the mobile number in custom module my code is

```
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum-length-10 validate-digits" id='adcontact' name='adcontact' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
```

but it is not working. when i enter only 2 or 3 digits form get submitted

Comment: Hi Nitin, 
what you did so that it works! I faced the same issue!

Answer (score 5):

If want to ten digital then you need do some code at `rules.js`

Copy rules.js from `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js`

to  put it to

```
app/code/[PackageName]/[ThemName]/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

Then add  new js rules **`mobiletendigit`** for 10 digit mobile after [**`mobileUK`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js#L219)

```
  "mobiletendigit": [
        function(value) {
            return value.length > 9 &&  value.length < 11 
            && value.match(/^\d{10}$/);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please specify a valid 10 digits mobile number')
    ],
```

**Remove `pub/static` folder contents and run deploy command,**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then you need add this new class `mobiletendigit` to your field.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry mobiletendigit validate-digits" id='adcontact' name='adcontact' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"/>
```

Comment: Question from @alexandre-iglesias-rodrigues : sorry for easy question, but in which file the field is in ?

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, i fallowed above step but it did not work for me.

Comment: Have u done  clear cache &  do static content deploy

Comment: Not working for me as well, even I have deploy the content

Comment: Hi Amit, Can you please tell me should we inject the rule.js file in di.xml?