# Magento2: how to add ten digit mobile number validation on contact us page?

Tags: magento2, validation, contact-us, mobile

I want to add ten digit mobile number validation on contact us page.

I already followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155878/validate-mobile-number-in-magento-2) but not working for me.